# Using Reflection to copy across equivalent properties between struct and class

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm making a game (see http://haighshroom.blogspot.com for context) and saving/loading the game using an XML file. It currently uses a different struct for the save format of each class, but continuing to update the save file structure is proving tiresome so I want to try and adopt the following generalised method.

Let's assume I have 3 classes, which all inherit from BaseClass:

Class1, which has Property1, Property2 (let's say all properties are ints)

Class2, which has Property2, Property3

Class3, which has Property1, Property3

Now my new generalised SaveStruct would look like this:

```
public struct EntityStruct
{
    public string ClassName;
    public int Property1;
    public int Property2;
    public int Property3;
    public EntityStruct()
    {
        ClassName = "";
        Property1 = Property2 = Property3 = 0;
    }
}
```

When saving/loading a particular entity, I want to achieve the following Pseudocode (both functions called from BaseClass):

```
public EntityStruct GetSaveStruct()
{
    EntityStruct es = new EntityStruct();
    es.ClassName = this.GetType().Name;
    if Exists(this.Property1) es.Property1 = Get(this.Property1);
    if Exists(this.Property2) es.Property2 = Get(this.Property2);
    if Exists(this.Property3) es.Property3 = Get(this.Property3);
}
public void LoadFromStruct(EntityStruct es)
{
    BaseClass e = (BaseClass)(Activator.CreateInstance(null, GV.NameSpace + es.ClassName).Unwrap());
    if Exists(e.Property1) Set(e.Property1 = es.Property1);
    if Exists(e.Property2) Set(e.Property2 = es.Property2);
    if Exists(e.Property3) Set(e.Property3 = es.Property3);
}
```

The parts I don't know how to define are:

-Exists(e.Property1) - this needs to use Reflection to determine whether the instance e has Property1 defined (we are calling this from BaseClass so we don't know without using Reflection).

-Get(e.Property1) - if Property 1 does exist for an instance e, we need to get its value

-Set(e.Property1 = es.Property1) - if Property 1 does exist from an instance e, we need to set its value

Many thanks.

Comment: You could go the reflection route or you could use a library such as automapper to do this, it would most likely work with zero configuration too using DynamicMap assuming your properties were like for like in naming convention

Comment: Or `var newObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeOtherClass>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject));` using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Automapper looks interesting, I've bookmarked it for later, but I've use the ShallowCopy method for now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starting point for all this is the [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. You can get an instance of this for your type using [`e.GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

To look for a field, use [`GetField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If that returns `null`, then the field doesn't exist at all.

If it returns a value (of type [`FieldInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) then use [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the value and [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set it.

Reflection is relatively slow, so if performance is a concern, grab the `System.Type` object ahead of time with something like [`System.Type.getType(name)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and also get the `FieldInfo` objects. You don't need the actual instance of the class to do either of those two operations, though obviously you need it to get and set the field values.

Comment: I've marked this as the accepted answer as it actually answers what I asked, although I used the ShallowClone method in the end.

Answer (score 4):

you can try use this code

```
public void ShallowCopyValues<T1, T2>(T1 firstObject, T2 secondObject)
{
    const BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
    var firstFieldDefinitions = firstObject.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);
    IEnumerable<FieldInfo> secondFieldDefinitions =     secondObject.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);

    foreach (var fieldDefinition in firstFieldDefinitions)
    {
        var matchingFieldDefinition = secondFieldDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(fd => fd.Name == fieldDefinition.Name &&
                                                                                  fd.FieldType == fieldDefinition.FieldType);
    if (matchingFieldDefinition == null)
        continue;

        var value = fieldDefinition.GetValue(firstObject);
        matchingFieldDefinition.SetValue(secondObject, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've actually used this method in the end, thanks for your help. I marked the other Answer as accepted simply because it answers the question, though.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. The fields are never matching. Could it be because some of them have get/set accessors, or because BaseClass doesn't define any of the properties it's searching for? (I'm calling ShallowCopyValues<BaseClass,EntityStruct>, but I need fields from Class1 : BaseClass copying over)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be skipping over all get/sets, and is only looking at BaseClass and higher classes. I don't think is going to be suitable as I can't write the class name at compile time.